# Find index of a tab in QTabWidget

Tags: qt, tabs, qtabwidget

I'm looking for a away to find an index of a certain tab in QTabWidget, so I can set the current index to this one. I remove some of the tabs so I don't want to use just an int to set the current tab, because in the future those removed tabs are going to be visible again and I don't want the code to depand on that.

So ideally I would like to be able to write something like that:

```
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tab->getIndex());
```

Is there some method like `getIndex()`?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#indexOf).

Comment: `ui->tabWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui->tab);`.

Comment: @ekhumoro, how to do the same if the tab widget is in another class?

Answer (score 6):

Use `ui->tabWidget->indexOf(your tab)`